# Liquibase changesets are not running in bootRepackage gradle task

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I have created liquibase changesets, in the Spring boot application. If I execute bootRun task then changesets get executed however, if I run bootRepackage changesets are not executed.

What additional configuration I need to do in order to run changesets with bootRepackage.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you add the [task tree](https://github.com/dorongold/gradle-task-tree) plugin to your script

```
plugins {
    id "com.dorongold.task-tree" version "1.3"
}
```

And then run

```
gradle bootRun bootRepackage taskTree
```

You should then see which tasks are run by the `bootRun` task which are not run by the `bootRepackage` task.

You'd then likely add a task dependency in `build.gradle`

```
bootRepackage {
    dependsOn someLiquibaseTask
}
```

Comment: Earlier I have added _org.liquibase:liquibase-core_ dependency at compile time but as I put that at run time it work for me, As tomcat get started chagesets executed.   Now my question here is compile time dependencies are not available at runtime?